# System.Web.Optimization error to add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't add reference to System.Web.Optimization, I have the MVC 4 installed, but I have this message when I try to add the reference "You don't have permission to open this file", but I'm using the system like adm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using nuget to get the latest version of System.Web.Optimization?

e.g. Type this into your package manager console

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`

I have a feeling there's an older version which isn't compatible with MVC 4.